# Ableton: keyboard shortcut for starting playing at beginning of song?

Tags: ableton-live, mac

In Ableton running on Mac, I'd like to use a keyboard shortcut to start playing the track from the beginning of the song, regardless of where the `Arrangement Insert Marker` (little downward pointing green arrow) is located.

I can hit spacebar twice to start over at the "beginning", but that only refers to the point where the `Arrangement Insert Marker` is.

Alternatively, it would also work there is a keyboard shortcut to change the `Arrangement Insert Marker` to the beginning of the song.

This would help speed up working on clips quite a lot.

Comment: https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-keyboard-shortcuts/#live-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut for "Move Insert Marker to Beginning" is [`Function`+left arrow key](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-keyboard-shortcuts/#live-keyboard-shortcuts)